# Facebook App Events Set App Version

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-events

I integrated with Facebook SDK and I am tracking FBAppEvents with it. So far the event reporting is working perfectly fine and the events all showed up in App Insights. However, I am having trouble setting the app version number. 
[image: See how the app version is unknown?]

According to [Apple's document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-events), all I need to do is to call [FBSettings setAppVersion:xxx]. However, this method is 
[deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x) and Facebook is suggesting using CFBundleVersion instead.

So instead of calling [FBSettings setAppVersion:], I set this CFBundleVersion in my app's [Appname]-Info.plist file but I still don't see the app version number show up(I put a value of 56 there).

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am using setAppVersion because CFBundleVersion does not work. I logged a bug with Facebook: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/665

Answer (score 1):

I set the Bundle version under the Info tab of the my target:

[image]